# About PHP QR Code library (part 1)

Tags: php, qr-code

I am using [PHP QR Code library](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/).
Below are my code:

**testqr.php**

```
<?php 
include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
?>

<html>
<body>
  <?php 
  $studentno = 123456;
  $image = $studentno.'.png';

  QRcode::png($studentno, $image);
  ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
</body>
</html>
```

From the above code, it will display a qr code on the web page and save an image file.

My question is can I just display a qr code on the web page **without** save an image file?

Comment: *"(part 1)"* - You mean, there's more (to come)? How many parts is this going to be?

Comment: instead of `<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />` use `<img src="<?php QRcode::png($studentno); ?>" />` and remove the line `QRcode::png($studentno, $image);` The second code line in your provided link!

Comment: Read the *Usage* section in the page you linked. It has a line of code that *"creates code image and outputs it directly into browser"*.

Comment: Read [the examples here](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/examples/).

Comment: @bansi I tried your code... However, there is no display qr code on the web page. It shows error message "The image X cannot be displayed because it contains errors."